# Check if input date falls within table of start and end dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'd like to run a query to check if an input date falls within any given term dates from a table.

Example table of Term Dates:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><th>termID</th><th>txtStartDate</th><th>txtFinishDate</th></tr>
<tr><td>37</td><td>2017-09-05 00:00:00</td><td>2017-12-15 23:59:00</td></tr>
<tr><td>38</td><td>2018-01-09 00:00:00</td><td>2018-03-29 23:59:00</td></tr>
<tr><td>39</td><td>2018-04-24 00:00:00</td><td>2018-07-06 23:59:00</td></tr>
<tr><td>40</td><td>2018-09-04 00:00:00</td><td>2018-12-14 23:59:00</td></tr>
<tr><td>41</td><td>2019-01-08 00:00:00</td><td>2019-03-29 23:59:00</td></tr>
<tr><td>42</td><td>2019-04-24 00:00:00</td><td>2019-07-05 23:59:00</td></tr></table>
```

Given an date, let's say today's date, does it fall between any of the rows' start and end date.

Example code approach

```
date = now()
for (row in rows):
    if date between row.txtStartDate and row.txtEndDate:
        return "yes"
```

I can use between logic with given dates but unsure how to apply this to the entire table.

```
select case when getdate() between '2019-04-24 00:00:00' and '2019-07-05 23:59:00' then 'yes' else 'no' END
```

Thanks

Comment: That code you're supplying there isn't T-SQL; how are you looking for this as a solution?

Comment: the code is an example of what i'd do if outside of SQL. In SQL, it would be be like Select case when getdate()  between ...logic... then "yes" else "no"

Comment: You have a column called "date" but it seems to have a time component.  I'm confused.

Comment: maybe the column should be called txtStartDateTime, but I have no control over this. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `WHERE` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable yt
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN yt.txtStartDate AND yt.txtEndDate
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I can just add a CASE when COUNT onto this statement and get my answer.

Comment: @DanWalters glad to help you!:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the table's columns instead of hard-coding the values. You do this using the table's alias and the proper column name.

```
DECLARE @InputDate DATE = '2019-01-05'

SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    YourTable AS T
WHERE
    @InputDate BETWEEN T.txtStartDate AND T.txtEndDate
```

Using a `WHERE` clause will filter the rows from the table and only display the ones in which the condition is true. If you move your condition as an expression of a new column (in the `SELECT` column list) then it will display all rows with this new expression:

```
DECLARE @InputDate DATE = '2019-01-05'

SELECT
    T.*,
    IsInputDateBetweenDates = CASE
        WHEN @InputDate BETWEEN T.StartDate AND T.EndDate THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No' END
FROM
    YourTable AS T
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach is great.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `IF EXISTS` also as shown below.

```
If Exists (Select 1 from YourTable where GETDATE() between txtStartDate AND txtEndDate)
Begin
    --Your if logic
end
else
begin
    --Your else logic
end
```